# Window.Closing event handler in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

*Following question is based on comment in this post: [MVVM Understanding Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32248041/475727)*

I said that this is codebehind, that does not violate the view and viewmodel separation of concerns:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
    }

    void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var canExit = ViewModel.ShowConfirmExitDlg();
        if (!canExit) e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

The comments was:

> Anything in code-behind can't be unit tested, and invoking the
>   creation of a dialog box is logic and therefore shouldn't be in the
>   view

I have two questions:

1. **Does this break MVVM separation of conerns?**
2. **How would you do it (better)**?

---

I could call the viewmodel method from xaml using some EventTriggers and CallMethod actions, but it does not make any difference.

I could do use event aggregator:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MainWindow(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        InitializeComponent();

        Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
    }

    void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var evt = new MainWindowClosingEvent();
        _eventAggregator.Publish(evt);
        e.Cancel = evt.IsCancel;
    }
}
```

and handle the event in viewmodel but does it bring any value? I still cannot unit test cancelling the windows closing event, but I have introduces publishing and subscribing that would be also worth unittestig. It's yet another layer of indirection

Maybe I could route the event to viewmodel:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Closing += ViewModel.OnWindowClosing;
   //or
   Closing += (o, e) => ViewModel.OnWindowClosing(e);
}
```

but I don't see much difference with the original sample.

IMHO, the connection between view and viewmodel cannot be unittested in viewmodel tests, so I either find a way how to test views or it is wild goose chase.

Comment: Are you trying to close the window from your viewmodel or just relay to your viewmodel that your window is closing?

Comment: Usually, window can be closed by clicking on X button, or pressing alt+f4 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to the first question I'm the person that made the comment so obviously my answer will be "Yes" :)

As for the second, interaction triggers are how I usually implement it myself, (although I've also used an attached behaviour when the circumstances dictated):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClosedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The Closing handler invokes the creation of a dialog box via a dependency injection framework while the Close handler causes the main view model to self-destruct:

```
public ICommand ClosingCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnClosing); } }
private void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
{
    #if !DEBUG
    var locman = Injector.Get<LocalizationManager>();
    var dlg = Injector.Get<CustomDialogViewModel>();
    dlg.Caption = locman[LogOffCaption];
    dlg.Message = locman[LogOffPrompt];
    dlg.OnCancel = (sender) =>
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        sender.Close();
    };
    dlg.Show();
    #endif
}

public ICommand ClosedCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(OnClosed); } }
private void OnClosed()
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```

This is a very simple example but it should be immediately obvious that this code can be easily tested by injecting mocked instances of both the localization manager and dialog box view model and then invoking the command handlers directly from the test framework.

It may be worth pointing out though that breaking pure MVVM is not necessarily a bad thing in all circumstances. Josh Smith appeared to be very much in support of no code-behind when wrote his original article on MVVM but by the time of "Advanced MVVM" he appears to have taken a softer stance, stating "Practical developers take the middle road and use good judgement to determine what code belongs where". In my seven or eight years of integrating WPF into full-stack architectures I personally have never encountered a case where pure MVVM couldn't implement a problem cleanly and elegantly, albeit admittedly at the expense of increased complexity in certain cases. Your own mileage will vary.

Comment: Thank you Mark, for the explanation. Do you have any reason special reason, why do you preffer EventToCommand instead of CallMethodAction? To me Command evokes that something should happen, event handlers that something has happen

Comment: I could be wrong but I didn't think CallMethodAction allows you to pass in the event arguments, which in the case of `Closing` is needed for user cancel? While this may not be the best example it certainly makes more sense for general GUI commands as it allows you to easily point the command binding elsewhere whereas with CallMethodAction you have to implement that logic in the handler itself (easy to do of course but it's another unnecessary layer). And finally there's the issue of CanExecute; again, you can do it other ways but ICommand supports it out-of-the-box.

Comment: Just FYI: [CallMethodAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723947(v=expression.40).aspx): public method whose signature matches that of an event handler.

Comment: How can I use CanExecute with Closing event? In this case, if `ClosingCommand.CanExecute` returned false, it would disable the MessageBox but windows would close anyway. It's confusing. Intuitivelly: `Closing cannot execute` means that closing should not proceed. Anyway I will mark this as answer, if nobody else answers

Comment: Ah! Ok, I was certainly wrong about the argument passing, thx for clarifying. And you're right about CanExecute, which is why I said `Closing` probably isn't a very good example.

Comment: Well I have chosen `Closing` by purpose, because it is not good example :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here, as I see it. Firstly, you can eliminate some of that code-behind by using the interactivity namespace and commands, for reference look into:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
       ICommand goes here - bind to your VM
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

when it comes to showing dialogs, you need to consider whether the dialog is view or view-model. When it comes to confirming the window closure, I think of that as purely view. So you can show that inside the code-behind of the Closing event, without IMHO breaking MVVM.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Actually, Im not creating dialog in codebehind, i'm just calling viewmodel. Viewmodel calls DialogService, that can be mocked in tests. When it comes to EventTriggers, I have mentioned them in my question as a possibility

Comment: No problem. I think in this case, for a close confirmation dialog, creating it in the view would be fine. There is no reason/advantage to creating it in the VM, and trying to test a close confirmation dialog seems excessive in my opinion. So, you asked 2 questions - does it break MVVM, and how would I do it better. Well, the above I think covers both of those points. :)